# Chapter Styling with background color out of textwidth

Tags: chapters, boxes, tcolorbox, backgrounds

I tried to use hbox/wbox, tabular and colorboxes.

Just look at image and this source.

Could anybody help with correct styling?

```
 \documentclass{book}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{tcolorbox}
 \makeatletter
 \def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
 \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
   \reset@font
   \parindent \z@ 
   \vspace*{10\p@}%
   \begin{tabular}{l l}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[center title,left=5pt,right=0pt,top=5pt,bottom=5pt,width=5cm, colback=red, colframe=red,enlarge left by=0mm,boxsep=5pt,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,]
        \fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont \textcolor{white}{\@chapapp{} \thechapter }
    \end{tcolorbox}
       &
    \begin{tcolorbox}[center title,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=5pt,bottom=5pt,colback=black, colframe=black,enlarge left by=0mm,boxsep=5pt,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,]
        \fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont \textcolor{white}{#1}
    \end{tcolorbox}
 \end{tabular}
 }

 \begin{document}
 \chapter{Introduction}
 \lipsum

 \chapter{Some very long title with many words and terms}
 \lipsum

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a tabular, you could use a `raster` with an `extruded` right box. Following code needs some geometry adjustments, but can help as starting point.

```
\documentclass{book}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
 \makeatletter
 \def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
 \def\@makechapterhead#1{%
   \reset@font
   \parindent \z@ 
   \vspace*{10\p@}%
   \begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=2, sharp corners, raster equal height, notitle, sharp corners, colupper=white, fontupper=\fontsize{14pt}{14pt}\selectfont, raster width=\linewidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep, raster force size=false]
    \begin{tcolorbox}[halign=center, valign=center, colback=red, colframe=red, add to width=-4cm]
        \@chapapp{} \thechapter
    \end{tcolorbox}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=black, colframe=black, extrude right by=\marginparwidth+\marginparsep]
        #1
    \end{tcolorbox}
 \end{tcbraster}
 }

 \begin{document}
 \chapter{Introduction}
 \lipsum

 \chapter{Some very long title with many words and terms}
 \lipsum

 \end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The below given MWE will set it for you:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox,array}
\makeatletter
\def\thickhrulefill{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 1ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \reset@font
  \parindent \z@
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  \def\xwidth{5cm}%
  \def\xsep{1pc}%
  \global\setbox0=\vbox{\begin{tcolorbox}[center title,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=5pt,bottom=5pt,colback=black, colframe=black,enlarge left by=0mm,boxsep=5pt,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,width=\textwidth+\xwidth]
       \parbox{\dimexpr(\textwidth-\xwidth-\xsep-\xwidth)}{\raggedright\fontsize{14pt}{18pt}\selectfont \color{white}#1}%
   \end{tcolorbox}}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}m{\xwidth}@{\hspace{\xsep}}m{\dimexpr(\textwidth-\xwidth-\xsep)}@{}}
   \begin{tcolorbox}[center title,left=5pt,right=0pt,top=5pt,bottom=5pt,, colback=red, colframe=red,enlarge left by=0mm,boxsep=5pt,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,width=\xwidth,height=\the\ht0-2.1mm]
       \fontsize{14pt}{18pt}\selectfont \textcolor{white}{\@chapapp{} \thechapter }
   \end{tcolorbox}
      &
      \box0
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Some very long title with many words and terms}
\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Some very long title with many words and terms Some very long title with many words and terms}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Please note that there is two command `\xwidth` and `\xsep` which will set the width of red box and sep between red and black box respectively. You can change it.